# Show GPS marker in surface view camera

Tags: android, gps, surfaceview

I have with me a set of latitude and longitude. I require to show this as a marker on a surface view that displays a camera. If I move out of the marker view it should dissappear, and reappear as I show move back in range.

Is there any way i could make an app like this? Any suggestions, libraries examples? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I've achieved what I needed:

1. I use android sensor to get the angle the phone is pointing at
2. Depending on this angle, I load the ImageView marrkers at runtime

**NOTE:** The Accelerometer and Magnetic sensors are the most useful for such an application. I suggest anyone to go through a tutorial for these first.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is what you want but the scenario you describe seems to be [Augmented Reality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_reality) so have a look ate [this](http://www.quora.com/Which-AR-Augmented-Reality-libraries-exist-on-Android-iPhone) answer in Quora where many libraries are pointed that can achieve this.

Comment: Yes it is an AR app. I've already been through the link you mentioned. Will update the thread when I find something that helps me. Thanks!